# I am completely new and don't understand what is wrong with my code. Could you just edit it and then reply it so that I can copy paste it

Tags: java, android

Please just edit it and reply it.
I don't want to learn any coding but just want to create an app.
This app function is to just display a youtube site with a banner ad and interstitial ads
 the errors which it is showing are these
Error:(39, 5) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(39, 12) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(39, 33) error: ';' expected
Error:(53, 5) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(53, 45) error: ';' expected
Error:(66, 2) error: reached end of file while parsing
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

My code->

```
    package cominfinitygaminghere.wixsite.httpsinfinitygaminghere.mumbojumbo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
        loadInterstitial();

        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChFur_NwVSbUozOcF_F2kMg");

    public void loadInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and reload the ad.
        if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            //code to go to next level of the app
        }
    }


    private InterstitialAd newInterstitialAd() {
        InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code for proceeding to next level here

            }
        });
        return interstitialAd;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: `I don't want to learn any coding but just want to create an app.` then pay somebody to do it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Need to insert closing bracket on `onCreate()`

```
package cominfinitygaminghere.wixsite.httpsinfinitygaminghere.mumbojumbo;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        WebView webView;

        private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
            loadInterstitial();

            AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();

            adView.loadAd(adRequest);

            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);

            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChFur_NwVSbUozOcF_F2kMg");

         }   // insert closing bracket here

        public void loadInterstitial() {
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

            // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and reload the ad.
            if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                //code to go to next level of the app
            }
        }


        private InterstitialAd newInterstitialAd() {
            InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
            interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    // Code for proceeding to next level here

                }
            });
            return interstitialAd;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your loadInterstitial() outside the **onCreate()** Method.

Answer (score 0):

Check this edited code.It may help you

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loadInterstitial();
        loadWebView();
    }

    private void loadWebView() {
        WebView webView;
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChFur_NwVSbUozOcF_F2kMg");
    }

    public void loadInterstitial() {
        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and reload the ad.
        if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            //code to go to next level of the app
        }
    }

    private InterstitialAd newInterstitialAd() {
        mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
        InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code for proceeding to next level here

            }
        });
        return interstitialAd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In onCreate Method you have not added the closing curly braces please add the closing curly bracket at line no 38.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
    loadInterstitial();

    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChFur_NwVSbUozOcF_F2kMg");
} // Add your closing bracket here
```

Comment: I have done same

Comment: It worked! Thanks!